# Directory.GetFiles from FTP site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ftp

I am using this method in my asp.net app to transfer upload files from a local dir to azure storage. I now want to do the same thing but with the files from an FTP folder. I have looked into `FtpWebRequest`, but not sure how or if it would work with this current method?

```
foreach (string strFile in Directory.GetFiles("myftpsite", "*.jpg"))
{
    blob = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(strFile);
    blob.UploadFile(strFile);                
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to send them from the blob container to a physical file on a remote location?

Comment: No, its going from an FTP folder TO the blob container

Comment: You can't go straight from FTP to BLOB. There needs to be a middle man somewhere.

Comment: ahh ok, do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

For listing all files in a FTP folder see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716.aspx

I don't know any way to read them directly so I would download them to the local machine and upload them to wherever you need them.

Comment: Hi, the files have to come straight from the FTP to the blob, no local machine involved.

Comment: Well there sure is RAM where you are executing the code. So maybe store the files temporarily there? Of course this is not a suitable solution for very large files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string[] directoryListDetailed(string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            /* Create an FTP Request */
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
            /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            /* When in doubt, use these options */
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
            ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
            StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
            /* Store the Raw Response */
            string directoryRaw = null;
            /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
            try
            {

                string[] separator = { "", " " };
                while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) 
                   {
                       bool flg = false; 

                     foreach (var word in ftpReader.ReadLine().Split (separator , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                     {

                         if (flg == true)
                         { directoryRaw += word.ToString() + "|"; flg = false; }
                         if (word.ToString () == "<DIR>")
                            flg = true;

                     }
                   } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Resource Cleanup */
            ftpReader.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
            /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
            try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
        return new string[] { "" };
    }
```

Comment: -1 You missed putting your Stream and StreamReader into `using` blocks.